# Triggers to sycnc status between two tables - how to avoid recursion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I try to optimize some of my processing. I have two tables (Job and Bucket) that both have a status that I want to synchronize. I.e. if someone changes the status of a job, then sometimes I change the status of a bucket, and sometimes when I change the status of a bucket, I want to change the status of the attached job. Sometimes in this regard means mostly "cancel" but also completion / errors flowing from the job to the bucket.

The reason they have 2 states is that (a) they are independent subsystems and it is possible for example to pause a job and (b) not every job is attached to a bucket ;)

I tried doing that with 2 triggers - one on update on Job, one on update on bucket, but it seems that whenever the trigger on job changes the bucket, the trigger on bucket will trigger. Funny enough, it seems that although this is an after update trigger, it seems that the trigger does not see the changes in the other table.... which leads to recursion.

The triggers are:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [grd].[Job_UpdateBucket]
   ON  [grd].[Job]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE
        [simstg].[Bucket]
    SET
        [Status] = i.[Status],
        [StatusTimestamp] = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM
        [simstg].[Bucket] b
        JOIN [inserted] i ON (b.[JobRef] = i.[Id])
    WHERE
        i.[Status] IN ('C', 'F', 'X', 'A')
        AND b.[Status] <> i.[Status]
        AND b.[Status] NOT IN ('X')

END
```

and

```
ALTER TRIGGER [simstg].[Bucket_UpdateJob] 
   ON  [simstg].[Bucket]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE
        [grd].[Job]
    SET
        [Status] = 'X',
        [LastUpdate] = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM
        [grd].[Job] j
        JOIN [inserted] i ON (j.Id = i.JobRef)
    WHERE
        i.[Status] = 'X'
        AND j.[Status] <> i.[Status]

END
```

This is - although I do SQL for a long time - the first time I have this type or recursion. I thought that the where condition would avoid a recursion, because it is an AFTER trigger, so if Job updates bucket, the bucket trigger should see the already changed status in job, so there should be no recursion.

This leads to two questions:

1: Am I wrong? If I update Job, then the trigger changes Bucket, then the trigger on Bucket should see the changed data in Job, or? That should make it possible to avoid the recursion because of the WHERE condition that compares that the status differs from the new one.

2: Any other way to avoid recursion here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented behaviour. [The docs state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799.aspx)

> These triggers fire when any valid event is fired, regardless of whether or not any table rows are affected.

So even though you have ensured no rows are affected in the update with the where clause, the update still happens which fires the trigger, and so on. I'd suggest the best way to manage this is using the [TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182737%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to find out which level of recursion you are at, e.g.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [simstg].[Bucket_UpdateJob] 
   ON  [simstg].[Bucket]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- CHECK TRIGGER NEST LEVEL HERE AND EXIT IF TOO HIGH
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN;

    UPDATE
        [grd].[Job]
    SET
        [Status] = 'X',
        [LastUpdate] = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM
        [grd].[Job] j
        JOIN [inserted] i ON (j.Id = i.JobRef)
    WHERE
        i.[Status] = 'X'
        AND j.[Status] <> i.[Status]

END
```

Another alternative would be to use the [`UPDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) function to see if the `Status` column has been updated before running the update, or more verbose still, checking if rows will be affected before doing the update:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [simstg].[Bucket_UpdateJob] 
   ON  [simstg].[Bucket]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE
            [grd].[Job]
        SET
            [Status] = 'X',
            [LastUpdate] = GETUTCDATE()
        FROM
            [grd].[Job] j
            JOIN [inserted] i ON (j.Id = i.JobRef)
        WHERE
            i.[Status] = 'X'
            AND j.[Status] <> i.[Status]
    END

END
```

Comment: I understand the trigger firing, BUT - my where clause limit should avoid the recursion. Imagine you set X on Job, then the trigger fires and sets X on Bucket. THen the trigger fires and - sets X on JOB... where X is not already set, and exactly here the recursion should end (because it should already be set).

Comment: Ah, got it. Oh my - what an issue. I overlooked that one. So.....  I went in and put NESTLEVEL in. Thanks.